# How can I configure kubctl cli without logging into the web UI?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

How can I configure kubectl cli without logging into the web UI?
My environment isn't up set and I want to run some kubctl commands.

Answer (score 1):

- [Install kubctl cli first](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/).

After that, you can issue the command.

e.g. `kubectl -s 127.0.0.1:8888 -n kube-system get pods`

Kudos to Arjun.